# UITableView and UITableViewCell from XIB bug?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, customization, xib

I'am trying to make `UITableView` with `UITableViewCell` from `.xib` programatically. 
But I don't know what I'am doing wrong. I have read couple of tutorials and it's looks like I'am doing everything ok, but it doesn't work. Can you guys help me?

That's how I'am loading UITableView and Cell

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
class GamesViewController : UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource
{

var gameTableView : UITableView?;

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    gameTableView = UITableView(frame: self.view.frame, style: UITableViewStyle.Plain);
    gameTableView!.delegate = self;
    gameTableView!.dataSource = self;
    gameTableView!
    var nib = UINib(nibName: "TaskCellView", bundle: nil);
    gameTableView!.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell");

    self.view.addSubview(gameTableView);

    super.viewDidLoad();

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
{
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning();
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!)
{

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return 4
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as? TaskCell;
    cell!.taskSkillLabel.text = "sdfsdf";
    return cell;
}
 }
```

And this is my custom view cell

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class TaskCell : UITableViewCell
{
 @IBOutlet var  taskSkillLabel : UILabel;

init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!)
{

    super.init(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier);
}

}
```

I can not post images but I end up with my cells one on each other.. and strange artefacts.
I even download someones code with similar working sample and situation is very similar.

Comment: @Piotr Your code looks good (according to my experience from obj-C). The problem may lay in cell .xib file, in .storyboard, or it is XCode 6 beta version issue. If it is an example project please send it on any git repository I will try to figure out where problem lays.

Comment: Thanks Szu it was problem that I did not add heightForRowAtIndex, I never used this making table view from storyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also add

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!,heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat
{
 return ATLEAST_YOUR_CELL_HIGHT
}
```

Comment: Thank you , it was super fast and easy :)